# How to insert two or more values into one column without col-span

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I want to make two or more values into one column but without cols-pan using [dataTables](https://datatables.net/), Below is example for table

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>FRUIT</td>
      <td>TASTE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>durian/banana/apel/tomato?</td>
      <td>Sweet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>starfruit/orange/avocado/rambutans</td>
      <td>Not good</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my code :

```
columns: [
  { data: 'name_fruit' },
  { data: 'taste_fruit' },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this reference https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

because it's use datatables too